# Mutable variable in a class

Tags: python, list, class, global

If I have a class like this.

```
class Person():

def __init__(self, name):
    self._name = name
    self._name_list = []
    if(self._name not in self._name_list):
        self._name_list.append(self._name)
father = Person("Michael")
mother = Person("Sharon")
```

```
>>>self._name_list

["Michael", "Sharon"]
```

How can I do this without creating a global variable? Everytime I instantiate a new person it creates their own list. But I need a list inside the scope of the class that appends a name everytime a new person is created.

Comment: don't do this. A class should not depend on how and why instances are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save it inside the class itself, like this:

```
class Person():
    _name_list = []

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
        if self._name not in self._name_list:
            self._name_list.append(self._name)

father = Person("Michael")
mother = Person("Sharon")

print(Person._name_list)
```

outputs:

```
['Michael', 'Sharon']
```

Comment: Note, however, that this is essentially a global variable.  If you don't want to have a global variable, you need to manage the list in a separate classe offering an `new_person()` method or similar which returns a new Person and adds it to the list.  (Also note that you probably want to use a set instead of a list.)

Comment: Wait... How come you did not add self. when created the list, but you were able to access the name list using self._name_list

Comment: This looks like a rather bad idea to store persons in a class variable in a class named `Person` (singular). What is wrong with creating a new object to store a collection of `Person` objects

Comment: @user13123 because instances have access to the class namespace

Comment: Can anybody answer my question?

Comment: You are going to have to do better than that to convince me @juanpaarrivillaga - if you need a `Person` to access a collection of `Persons`, it is surely better to give them a pointer to a collection of `Persons`... Now you have a  class `Person` that must do the housekeeping for the `Persons`!?!

Comment: @user12123 class variables are not part of the instance and do not requires self

Comment: But then it does after init?

Comment: yes... You should really get the explanation from @FranciscoCouzo, he is the one that proposed this design to you!

Comment: @user13123 `_name_list` is an attribute of the class itself, when an instance of a class can't find an attribute on itself, it tries finding it on their parent classes, in this case `Person`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
people = []
class Person():
   def __init__(self, name):
       self._name = name
       if self._name not in people:
           global people
           people.append(self._name)

person = Person('name1')
person1 = Person('name2')
print(people)
```

Output:

```
['name1', 'name2']
```